# How to get values of latent variable in factor anlaysis

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, factor-analysis

I conducted  exploratory factor analysis (EFA) to uncover the underlying factor structure(shown as below). My question is how to obtain the value for each latent factor (factor 1,2,3,4)? For example, for factor 1, it is a latent variable that consists of con1,con2 con3 con4. To get the value of factor 1 for each observation, is that taking the mean value of con1,con2 con3 con4?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, the table you have shown is incomplete. Each factor is a linear combination of all the variables. Your table shows the loadings that are above some value. This is useful for the analyst as it helps highlight the structure, but the other variables are also in the factor.

Second, for each person, each factor score is the loading times the value of that variable.  .88*Con1 + 0.82*Con2  + .....

for all 13 variables.